# Why wont this image move?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

As far as I know, this program should be moving the image when I press the arrow keys/WASD, and I'm not sure why its not. 
To speed up the reading, I can explain what it is. I started out by defining a few things, just for the names for convenience, then inside of my while loop, I started using the getkey, and I set it up so that when you press an arrow key, it should paint the screen white, then +/- 10 to the x/y, then it should redraw the pictures at the new locations, yet for some reason, it just doesn't do any of the code after those If statements.

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
import curses
def print_there(x, y, text):
     sys.stdout.write((x, y, text))
     sys.stdout.flush()
pygame.init()
bckgrnd_clr = 'gray95'
x,y=0,0
width = 1280
height = 704
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
GameImage = pygame.image.load("Images/stage.png")
Player = pygame.image.load("Images/Knight.png")
Blank = pygame.image.load("Images/Blank.png")
pygame.display.set_caption("Zackarys Game")
screen.blit(GameImage, (0,0))
screen.blit(Player, (y,x))
pygame.display.update()
FPS = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
white = [255 , 255, 255]
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
          if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
               screen.fill(white)
               x = x - 10
               screen.blit(GameImage, (0,0))
               screen.blit(Player, (y,x))
          if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
               screen.fill(white)
               x = x + 10
               screen.blit(GameImage, (0,0))
               screen.blit(Player, (y,x))
          if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
               screen.fill(white)
               y = y - 10
               screen.blit(GameImage, (0,0))
               screen.blit(Player, (y,x))
          if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
               screen.fill(white)
               y = y + 10
               screen.blit(GameImage, (0,0))
               screen.blit(Player, (y,x))
          if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
               pygame.display.quit()
               pygame.quit()
               sys.exit()
               running = False
```

Please let me know as soon as you can.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed your code. I do not know what the module 'curses' was for. The problem was that you only updated the display once (which disables animation). Another problem was that you were trying to blit the image only when the event keys were pressed which would have been a problem if you needed to regularly update the display. Here is the updated code (I also fixed your x's and y's).

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
def print_there(x, y, text):
    sys.stdout.write((x, y, text))
    sys.stdout.flush()
pygame.init()
bckgrnd_clr = 'gray95'
x,y=0,0
width = 1280
height = 704
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
GameImage = pygame.image.load("Images/stage.png")
Player = pygame.image.load("Images/Knight.png")
Blank = pygame.image.load("Images/Blank.png")
pygame.display.set_caption("Zackarys Game")
screen.blit(GameImage, (0,0))
screen.blit(Player, (y,x))
FPS = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
white = [255 , 255, 255]
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(white)
    screen.blit(GameImage, (0,0))
    screen.blit(Player, (x, y))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
           if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
              x = x - 10
           if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
              x = x + 10
           if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
              y = y - 10
           if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
              y = y + 10
           if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
               pygame.display.quit()
               pygame.quit()
               sys.exit()
               running = False
    pygame.display.update()
```